# Using vlookup to look for values in multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table. I have another table with 52 rows for each week and I intend to add each name that the week is assigned to in the shown table.

The assigned weeks are divided into two halves of the year. Is there a way to use vlookup to look for a week number in the two columns and then return the name?

**First table**

[image: First table]

**Second table**

[image: Second table]

Comment: Could you provide the "another table with 52 rows for each week"?

Comment: I've added the second table in the edit. Just a table with one column going from 1 to 52 to get what value to look for in the source

Right now I have two separate formulas. One formula for 1 to 26 and another for the weeks 27 to 52. But I was wondering if there's a way to look for a number in two columns instead of one, using Vlookup

Comment: If you have only 3 columns in the first table it would be better to have a single column for week number which would treat it like a primary key. Then just repeat team member names when necessary. The benefit of readability in the current structure complicates the formula needed for the 2nd table. If you normalized the data you could have used a simpler `IFERROR(VLOOKUP())` combination.

Comment: Sure that's one way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the tables are arranged as in the first image below, try the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$C$8,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F2,$B$2:$C$8,2,FALSE))
```

`VLOOKUP` is used for both columns in combination with `IFERROR`. Checking the first column for the lookup value. If found it is returned. If not found, meaning there is an error, the second `VLOOKUP` checks the second column and returns the lookup value.

Drag it down to fill the other cells. Make the appropriate change so the ranges match yours.

**Formula**
[image: Formula]

**Result**
[image: Result]

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought maybe there's a way to give arguments with Vlookup that make it check the first and the second column since I'm new to it, but I guess I have to use if conditions.